# IIS Windows Authentication: Angular 4 + .Net Core 2.0 - Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: angular, iis, windows-authentication, asp.net-core-2.0

I have tried multiple answered StackOverflow questions on this topic but none of them have worked successfully for me.  I keep getting this error in the console:

Failed to load http://myserver:8080/api/user: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://myserver' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.

Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://myserver","http://localhost").AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowCredentials()));
    services.AddMvc(config => config.Filters.Add(typeof(CustomExceptionFilter))).AddJsonOptions(x => x.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);
    services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
    services.AddSingleton(Environment);
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute()...// All of my routes
    });
}
```

I have tried also using AllowAnyOrigin() as well in the AddPolicy method.

When I view my API in the browser, it works fine when I hit it directly: http://myserver:8080/api/user, however, it doesn't work when my Angular app makes the same call:

```
ngOnInit() {
    return this.http.get(`${environment.apiUrl}/api/user`).subscribe(
        response => { ... }
    );
```

environment.prod.ts:

```
export const environment = {
    apiUrl: "http://myserver:8080",
    production: true
};
```

Has anyone else experienced these issues between Angular4 and .Net Core 2.0 apps and know of a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add proxy configuration to your angular cli:

proxy config file:

```
{
 "/api/*": {
   "target": "http://myserver:8080",
   "secure": false,
   "logLevel": "debug",
   "changeOrigin": true
}
```

And add it to your ng serve script:

```
"start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json"
```